# want to disable adding of rooms but should be able to display the rooms in converse.js

Tags: converse.js

Can anybody help me out if it's possible to make the form for joining a room invisible and to make the list of rooms take the entire space in the rooms tab. Please help me out.

[Image showing the part to be made invisble](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zWnH.png)

Comment: resolved it by modifying converse.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember there is no config setting to do that, but you can hide the relevant section with CSS.

Something like this:

```
form.converse-form.add-chatroom {
    display: None;
}
```

You'll probably also want to set [auto_list_rooms](https://conversejs.org/docs/html/configuration.html#auto-list-rooms) to `true` when you call `converse.initialize` so that rooms are shown automatically (i.e. without having to click a button which won't be visible after you hide it).

Comment: thanks for the solution, i had done the but in js file. This is good one